# Python3: Converting a nested dict into a list of objects with "children" and "leaf"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm currently trying to convert a nested dict into a list of objects with "children" and "leaf".
Here my input dict and the output I'm trying to obtain:

Input:

```
{
    "a": {
        "aa": {}
    },
    "b": {
        "c": {
            "d": {
                'label': 'yoshi'
            }
        },
        "e": {},
        "f": {}
    }
}
```

I try to obtain this:

```
[
    {
        "text": "a",
        "children": [
            {
                "text": "aa",
                "leaf": "true"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "text": "b",
        "children": [
            {
                "text": "c",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "text": "d",
                        "leaf": "true",
                        "label": "yoshi"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "e",
                "leaf": "true"
            },
            {
                "text": "f",
                "leaf": "true"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tried a few unflatten python lib on pypi but not one seems to be able to output a list format like this.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question but I think you could benefit from some information on nodes: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_nodes.htm

Comment: What are the rules for `label`?

Answer (score 1):

I have commented the function as I feel necessary.

```
def convert(d):
    children = []
    #iterate over each child's name and their dict (child's childs)
    for child, childs_childs in d.items():
        #check that it is not a left node
        if childs_childs and \
           all(isinstance(v,dict) for k,v in childs_childs.items()):
            #recursively call ourselves to get the child's children
            children.append({'text': child,
                             'children': convert(childs_childs)})
        else:
            #if the child is a lead, append to children as necessarry
            #the **-exploded accommodates the 'label':'yoshi' item
            children.append({'text': child,
                             'leaf': True,
                             **childs_childs})
    return children
```

which gives:

```
[
 {
  "text": "a",
  "children": [
   {
    "text": "aa",
    "leaf": true
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "text": "b",
  "children": [
   {
    "text": "c",
    "children": [
     {
      "text": "d",
      "leaf": true,
      "label": "yoshi"
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "text": "e",
    "leaf": true
   },
   {
    "text": "f",
    "leaf": true
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough solution.  Here I assumed that all labeled nodes are leaves that just have label information.

```
def make_objects(d):
    result = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v == {}:
            result.append({"text": k, "leaf":True})
        elif len(v) ==1 and "label" in v:
            result.append({"text": k, "leaf":True, "label": v.get("label")})  
        else: 
            result.append({"text": k, "children": make_objects(v)}) 
    return result
```

With your example input as `d`:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(make_objects(d))
```

prints

```
[{'children': [{'leaf': True, 'text': 'aa'}], 'text': 'a'},
 {'children': [{'children': [{'label': 'yoshi', 'leaf': True, 'text': 'd'}],
                'text': 'c'},
               {'leaf': True, 'text': 'e'},
               {'leaf': True, 'text': 'f'}],
  'text': 'b'}]
```

Comment: Works very similarly to mine, but mine accommodates for other items :p +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution (`data` is your input dictionary):

```
def walk(text, d):
    result = {'text': text}

    # get all children
    children = [walk(k, v) for k, v in d.items() if k != 'label']
    if children:
        result['children'] = children
    else:
        result['leaf'] = True

    # add label if exists
    label = d.get('label')
    if label:
        result['label'] = label

    return result


[walk(k, v) for k, v in data.items()]
```

Output:

```
[{'text': 'a', 'children': [{'text': 'aa', 'leaf': True}]},
 {'text': 'b',
  'children': [{'text': 'c',
    'children': [{'text': 'd', 'leaf': True, 'label': 'yoshi'}]},
   {'text': 'e', 'leaf': True},
   {'text': 'f', 'leaf': True}]}]
```